# Gmail script and bounce to telegram

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, telegram, google-apps

I'm new and I'm interested in the google scripts for my project. Only that alone I'm not succeeding and I was looking for help if possible. I have this need: I have to extract the body of the message from the email and then eleaborate it, then I have to break up the text to create a new body. So I have to send this new body of the message to a telegram bot. is it possible to do such a thing? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GmailApp.getMessageById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getMessageById(String)) followed by [getBody()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getBody()) call in Google Apps Script to get the body text for a given email id. See the following sample:

```
var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; // Get first thread in inbox
var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // Get first message
Logger.log(message.getBody()); // Log contents of the body
```

You could then use the [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) class to send a HTTP request to your external service